# Differential of the square of a variable proof from "Calculus for the Practical Man"

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, differential

I have been trying to get a deeper understanding of calculus and started reading the book "Calculus for the Practical Man". I enjoy the book a lot, but there is a proof about the differential of the square of a variable that I just can't understand. The proof goes like this:

Let $z = mx$ where $m$ is a constant and $x$ is a variable, then $z$ is a dependent variable. Then
$$
z^2 = m^2x^2
$$
We differentiate both sides for both of the equations:
$$
dz = mdx, d(z^2) = m^2d(x^2)
$$
We divide the second results by the first results:
$$
\frac{d(z^2)}{dz} = m * \frac{d(x^2)}{dx}
$$
And then we divide this result by the original equation $z = mx$ to eliminate the constant $m$:
$$
\frac{d(z^2)}{dz} * \frac{1}{z} = \frac{d(x^2)}{dx} * \frac{1}{x}
$$
The conclusion that the author draws from this last part, is that the derivative of the square of a variable divided by the variable itself is the same for *any* two variables x and z. I understand the rest of the proof, but I just can't understand why the proof until here proves that the derivative of the square of a variable divided by the variable is the same for *any* two variables. In this proof we used a variable $z$ which was equal to $mx$. As an example I tried to apply the same proof for a variable $z = x + 1$ but could not reduce to the last equality, so I am confused. How about a $z$ which does not depend on $x$ at all, how would that look like? I am a little lost here, so I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think $z= x+1$ works because equation needs to be in the form $z=mx$

Comment: @Scilent144 I think so too, but this opens up two questions: 1) If z **has** to be in the form of $mx$, I don't think that this proof actually proves that the derivative of the square of a variable divided by the variable is the same value for *any* two values. 2) I would actually expect this proof to still work with  for example $z = x + 1$ because with the knowledge we already have, the derivative of $x^2 (2x)$ times $\frac{1}{x}$ would give us 2, and the derivative of $(x+1)^2 (2(x+1))$ times $\frac{1}{(x+1)}$ would also give us 2, making the equation work, so I am confused :/